# Need help making https request using HTTPClient with custom headers

Tags: https, arduino, arduino-esp32

I'm currently using the following Arduino code on an ESP32 (I've taken out non-relevant parts) to make an https request for a binary file from a server, to store in SPIFFS. However I now need to set a custom header, and so need to use the https.beginRequest() method. But this method does not take a WiFiClientSecure reference, and so I cannot use HTTPS for this. Can the standard Arduino lib actually perform https requests with custom headers, or is there another lib for this?

```
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  client.setInsecure(); // Not using certificate check while testing

  HTTPClient https;
  https.useHTTP10(true);
  Serial.println("https.begin...");
  if (https.begin(client, "https://path.to.binary.file")) {  // HTTPS
    Serial.println("Sending GET request...");
    //https.sendHeader("X-device: 12345678"); // Cannot use here

    // start connection and send HTTP header
    int httpCode=https.GET();
    Serial.printf("Response code: %u\n",httpCode);
    Serial.printf("Content length: %u\n",https.getSize());
    uint32_t bytesRead=0;
    uint8_t b;
    while(client.connected()){
      while(client.available()){
       ++bytesRead;
        b=client.read();
        Serial.printf("0x%02x ",b);
        if((bytesRead%16)==0){
          Serial.println();
        }
      }
    }
    Serial.printf("\nBytes read: %u\n",bytesRead);
    https.end();
  }else{
    Serial.println("Could not connect to server");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> https.sendHeader("X-device: 12345678");

The `https.sendHeader()` does not *add* header as you think it was, it actually send out all the headers (except body) starting from `GET / HTTP/1.1` all the way till the separator between http headers and http body, see the [source code](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp#L1186-L1232).

To **add** a custom header to the http request, you need to call [http.addHeader()](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp#L1040) with

```cpp
https.addHeader("X-device", "12345678");
```

Here is the code that should work:

```cpp
void loop() {
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  client.setInsecure(); // Not using certificate check while testing

  HTTPClient https;
  https.useHTTP10(true);
  Serial.println("https.begin...");
  if (https.begin(client, "https://httpbin.org/get")) {  // HTTPS
    Serial.println("Sending GET request...");
    https.addHeader("X-device", "12345678");
    int httpCode=https.GET();
    Serial.printf("Response code: %u\n",httpCode);
    Serial.printf("Content length: %u\n",https.getSize());
    Serial.println("HTTP response:");
    Serial.println(https.getString());

    https.end();
  }else{
    Serial.println("Could not connect to server");
  }

  while(1);
}
```

This code will return the response from https://httpbin.org/get which basically echo back all the headers sent/added, plus client IP and request URL:

```
https.begin...
Sending GET request...
Response code: 200
Content length: 265
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "ESP32HTTPClient", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-64392c39-768ce2a95ca639bc0f79e256", 
    "X-Device": "12345678"
  }, 
  "origin": "xxx.xx.xx.xx", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this as the documentation is incorrect. The `https.addHeader()` method CAN be used before calling GET, and does work. The official documentation states that it can only be used between the `beginRequest` and `endRequest` calls.